# python3 recognizes tensorflow, but doesn't recognize any of its attributes

Tags: tensorflow, attributeerror

I am getting the following errors:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope'
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'squared_difference'
```

[tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) is installed:

```
>> pip3 list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow           2.0.0    
tensorflow-estimator 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 24):

TensorFlow 2.0 cleaned up some of the APIs. Mathematical functions such as `squared_difference()` are now under `tf.math`.

There is no `tf.variable_scope()` in TensorFlow 2.0. I suggest reading [this post](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) with examples on how to migrate your code to TF2.

If you want your code to be compatible with older versions of TensorFlow, you can use `tf.compat.v1.variable_scope()`

Comment: thanks, what about the other attribute errors? it is not only failing to recognize variable_scope, but also: name_scope, contrib, get_variable, AUTO_REUSE, float32, placeholder, Saver, Session, global_variables_initializer, ...

Comment: Most of these have been replaced completely. There are no scopes, sessions or placeholders in TF2 and variables don't need to be initialized. Some others are just cleaned up.

Comment: yikes, okay, guess i have to rewrite my code or use the older version of tensorflow. didn't realize there was such a big change that occurred.

Comment: you can always run it at compatibility mode: `tf.compat.v1....`, but you'll have to adapt sooner or later